# Devise notices displayed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise for User authentication, and its working as its supposed to. it gives me all the notices, but theres one thing. i have this code, in my `applicaton.html.haml`:

```
  - flash.each do |name, msg|
    .alert
      %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
      = msg
```

for my own notices, and given that fact, all devise notices are doubled. They are displayed both by devise and by my code here. what can i do to prevent devise notices be displayed by code above?

Comment: If you remove this or comment it, do you see the devise messages still?

Comment: i do, but just one, thats how i know its my code fault

Comment: When you first install devise it tells you to put two `<p>` tags with flash messages in your application layout. Did you do that? If you already have flash message code, you won't need that bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

if you have that code in your application.html you shouldnt need to use the two

tags that come with devise. Just have all the alerts come through your own code.